# IS it possible to specify where to download a file in hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, download

I am trying to download a file via an hyperlink after converting a html table to csv, here is my code:

```
function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

    var $rows = $table.find('tr'),
       ...
        csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
           ...

        // Data URI
        csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

    $(this)
        .attr({
        'download': filename,
        'href': csvData,
        'target': '_blank'
    });
}
```

It works fine , onclick the hyperlink a "save as" pop up window is opened to save the file and download it.I don't want to pop up the "save as" but automatically download the file to the default download location set in the browser.

Is there any idea to get the download location and set it appropriately. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For security reason, browsers doesn't allow to write anything in client side filesystem without user interaction.

Otherwise you could overwrite its files from server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can link your file and add download attribute like so:

```
<a href="file.csv" download="namefile.csv">file CSV (2Kb)</a>
```

[edit] I'm not sure to answer the question ...

Comment: yes it is already what I have don, am looking for a way to tell the ref that you will not pop up the "save as" window but download it automatically to the default location